# Non-trivial ADB issue

Tags: usb, adb

I have XPS 9550, and previously I successfully connect Nexus 5 to this host.

but now I've got Pixel with Usb3 cable. and it's not in list of connected devices (in Ubuntu, Windows works)

```
veon@veon-XPS-15-9550:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a5c:6410 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 18d1:4ee2 Google Inc. Nexus 4 (debug)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2b95 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

while it still works well with Nexus 5.

so where should I start debug?

Comment: Did you enable Developer Options and USB Debugging on your Pixel?

Comment: yes, I connected to Pixel from Windows,

Comment: ok, after several hours I saw it in android studio device list for a second. when I approved certificate it is gone